# How do i append an array to an already existing state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to implement pagination using react but cannot seem to figure out a way to append the new response to an already existing state variable.

I'm trying to implement a load more functionality wherein the data is appended to the list itself.

```
  const handleLoadMoreClick = () => {
    let tempObj = postparem;
    tempObj.pagenumber = tempObj.pagenumber + 1;
    setPostparem(tempObj);
    getProductChildMenu(APIProductList, postparem);   
    setCopyMenu(...copyMenu, productChildMenu);
  };
```

Currently the map function is running iterating over productChildMenu so it replaces the data but i want to append the data in productChildMenu to copyMenu.

I tried iterating over productChildMenu and pushing each element to copyMenu but it is coming out undefined or if i push it completely at once, it creates a 2d array which does not iterate in map correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you are doing with `tempObject` here:

```js
let tempObj = postparem;
// this is wrong.
tempObj.pagenumber = tempObj.pagenumber + 1;
setPostparem(tempObj);
```

Even though you call the variable `tempObj` a "temporary object", it is not a new object. It is just a reference to the object stored in the variable `postparem`.

So your code is identical to the (equally wrong) `postparem.pagenumber = postparem.pagenumber + 1`.

Instead, you really have to *create a new object*:

```js
let tempObj = {
  ...postparem,
};
```

and then you can either modify that, or already introduce your change on object creation.
That would look like

```js
let tempObj = {
  ...postparem,
  pagenumber: postparem.pagenumber + 1,
};
setPostparem(tempObj);
```

Or even a bit shorter:

```js
setPostparem({
  ...postparem,
  pagenumber: postparem.pagenumber + 1,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do the following to merge 2 objects into your state.

```
  const handleLoadMoreClick = () => {
    ...    
    ...    
    setCopyMenu({...copyMenu, ...productChildMenu});
  };
```